# Как правильно зациклить функцию?

Tags: javascript

Как правильно зациклить функцию:

```
function F1(sname, cls) {
  $.get('file.php?stname=' + sname, function(data){
    $('#' + cls).html(data);
  });
  setTimeout(F1, 5000);
}

$("td[data-pll]").each(function () {
  var startat = $(this).attr("data-pl");
  endat = $(this).attr("data-plll");
  F1(startat, endat);
});
```

Функция выполняется только один раз, `setTimeout` не работает, подскажите, где ошибка?

Comment: `setTimeout(function() {F1(sname, cls);}, 5000);`

Comment: спасибо! все работает! напишите это ответом и я поставлю как правильный ответ!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setTimeout` принимает функцию без параметров. Заверните вызов Вашей функции в другую - анонимную:

`setTimeout(function() {F1(sname, cls);}, 5000);`